# smo compatibility with previous version

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, smo

I develope a C# application that works with SMO Classes and uses these assemblies :

1. Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll
2. Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll
3. Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
4. Microsoft.SqlSever.SqlEnum

and I use SQL Server 2012 assemblies, therefore my App will work with sql server 2012 and I must install sql server 2012 and shared mangement object 2012 on target machine in order to my app work correctly.
now I want to Know if sql2005/2008 is installed on target machine then my App can work with that sql engine or Necessarily I must install sqlserver 2012 ?